# Families of triangulations of polygons in the plane

Tags: geometry, co.combinatorics

Let $P$ be a polygon in the plane.  An "efficient" triangulation of $P$ is one that introduces no new vertices.  We require that all introduced edges be straight and inside $P$.  Every polygon in the plane has at least one efficient triangulation.

Let $R$ be a regular polygon with $n$ sides and think of it as the archetypical polygon with $n$ sides.  Let $F$ be a family of efficient triangulations of $R$.  We call $F$ "realizable" if there is a polygon $P$ with $n$ sides and an isomorphism of $R$ to $P$ as polygons so that the family $F$ is carried exactly to the set of efficient triangulations of $P$.

Is there a reasonable characterization of realizable families?

Comment: I think the only obstruction is that the edges of the triangles have to be realized by straight edges in the interior between vertices. So you could just compute all of the straight edges in the interior, and take the subset of triangulations which only use edges from this set. Is this not a sufficient characterization? 

Comment: Do you have a small example of a non-realizable set?

Comment: Is it okay with you if $P$ is self-intersecting? In which case I'm trying to decide if this is equivalent to the question of which rank 2 matroids are positroids, as in http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.1018

Comment: Allen: I had in mind everything embedded.  Brendan:  There is much I am not sure of.  If vertices of the polygon are numbered in circular order from 1 to n and the edge (1,3) is not usable and the edge (2,4) is not usable, can the edge (1,4) be usable?  If the answer is no, then there should be examples. Ian: the question starts with a family of abstract triangulations and then asks if there is a real life embedding representing exactly that family.  I think you are starting with the embedding and asking what the family is.

Comment: Okay, I have a (1,3), (2,4) out and (1,4) in example (see my comment of a minute or two ago), so I am less sure there are non-realizable families.  I have reasons in another language for believing so and I will see if I can really make the translation.

Comment: Brendan:  In the hexagon, leave out of the family all triangulations that do NOT use the edge (1,4).  In the picture http://11011110.livejournal.com/76142.html, this leaves out all four of the triangulations that are around the central square.  My instinct is that there are enough edges left to argue that the P in question has to be strictly convex.

Comment: Matt: Perhaps Agol's comment suggests that one can reduce the problem to characterizing which sets of edges can be realized as all the interior straight edges for some polygon?

Comment: Lee: Right.  I guess I made a too formal statement of the problem.  That is what I had in mind.  

Comment: Any four of the five triangulations of the pentagon give an example of a "non-realizable family". More generally, any set of triangulations whose union is the complete graph but which does not consist of the whole set of triangulations is not realizable...

Comment: Are you interested in convex polygons only? If so, how do your *efficient* triangulations differ from the conventional question of noncrossing triangulations of an n-gon which are counted by Catalan numbers $C_{n-2}$?

Comment: @MattBrin If I understand your question correctly, the families of efficient triangulations of some n-gon are the families in which every triangulation shares some outermost diagonal, i.e. a diagonal which forms a triangle with two outer edges of the polygon. Every triangulation in this family is of course a triangulation of the $n-1$ gon.

Comment: @Robert Frost: no, the polygon P is not convex, but R is.  The "only" non convex quadrilateral has only one triangulation, but the convex ones have two.  Thus for n=4 all families (which I realize had better be non-empty) are realizable: the family with one element and the family with two.  Santos seems to have the most complete answer so far where he shows that non-realizable families start with n=5.